# json? in Django URL regex

Tags: regex, django, json, django-urls

This question might reveal a gaping hole in my knowledge of json queries, but I'm trying to get json data to display on a view with the following URL.

```
http://localhost:8000/structures/hydrants/json?id=%3D2/
```

Here's my URL regex:

```
url(r'^hydrants/json\\?id=(?P<hydrant_id>\d+)/$', views.hydrant_json, name='hydrant_json'),
```

and the view:

```
def hydrant_json(request, hydrant_id):
    hydrant = get_object_or_404(Hydrant, pk=hydrant_id)
    data = [hydrant.json()]
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

Obviously, the question mark is throwing it off, because if I make the regex

```
url(r'^hydrants/json/id=(?P<hydrant_id>\d+)/$', views.hydrant_json, name='hydrant_json'),
```

then the following URL will work:

```
http://localhost:8000/structures/hydrants/json/id%3D2/
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Structurally, where would I put request.GET.get('id', '')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the data as `GET` parameters, you can simply do:

```
url(r'^hydrants/json/$', views.hydrant_json, name='hydrant_json'),
url(r'^hydrants/json/(?P<hydrant_id>\d+)/$', views.hydrant_json, name='hydrant_json_with_key'),
```

and views:

```
def hydrant_json(request, hydrant_id=None):
    if not hydrant_id:
       hydrant_id = request.GET.get('id')

    if not hydrant_id: #if hydrant_id is not received for some reason, throw 404. 
        raise Http404

    hydrant = get_object_or_404(Hydrant, pk=hydrant_id)
    data = [hydrant.json()]
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

Here, you are defining flexible ways of sending `hydrant_id` into the view.

By default, for a GET request, `request.GET` would have all the get parameters - example: `?id=123`

Also, if you want to send `hydrant_id` as a part of the URL, You can just do

```
http://localhost:8000/structures/hydrants/json/302/
```

Please note, `3D2` would never get matched as a URL in the regex because your URL is looking for `\d+` which is digits only.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Should the first if be if hydrant_id?
Also, the 3D2 is from the %3D which is an equal sign.

Comment: no.. It should be `if not` The logic is-  if the `hydrant_id` does not come via URL, see if it is present as a GET parameter.